# Regex to remove string after file extension

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to query for a service path from which results should resemble  C:\directory\sub-directory\service.exe

Some results however also include characters after the .exe file extension, for example output may resemble one of the following:

- C:\directory\sub-directory\service.exe ThisTextNeedsRemoving
- C:\directory\sub-directory\service.exe -ThisTextNeedsRemoving
- C:\directory\sub-directory\service.exe /ThisTextNeedsRemoving

i.e. ThisTextNeedsRemoving may be proceeded by a space, hyphen or forward slash.

I can use the regex  -replace '($*.exe).*' to remove everything after, but including the .exe file extension, but how do I keep the .exe in the results?

Comment: `($*.exe).*` will not match anything without `(?m)` modifier. I guess you need `^(\S+).*` (or `^(\S+\.exe) .*`) and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Try `$s -replace '^(\S+\.exe) .*','$1'` if `$s` is your input.

Comment: Do not use lookbehind in real production, use my approach with a capture and a backreference. Lookbehinds are the worst when it comes to performance. Although in this case it is not critical, it is a good idea to get accustomed to best practices.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew post as answer, I will upvote. Also it's hard for someone to accept your answer if it's not an answer!

Comment: @briantist: I do not believe in "try this" answers, and I did not have time to write a full answer before.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no prob, thanks for posting, +1  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a look-around:

```
$txt = 'C:\directory\sub-directory\service.exe /ThisTextNeedsRemoving'

$txt -replace '(?<=\.exe).+', ''
```

This uses a look-behind which is a zero-width match so it doesn't get replaced.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/j4wgem1Rt5GkqHt7)

Answer (score 2):

Using lookbehind is possible, but note that lookbehinds are only necessary when you need to specify some rather complex condition or to obtain overlapping matches. In most cases, when you can do without a lookbehind, you should consider using a non-lookbehind solution because it is rather a costly operation. It is easier to check once if the current character is not a whitespace than to also check if each of these symbols is preceded with something else. Or a whole substring, or a more complext pattern.

Thus, I'd suggest using a solution based on capturing mechanism, with a backreference in the replacement part to restore the captured substring in the result:

```
$s -replace '^(\S+\.exe) .*','$1'
```

or - for paths containing spaces and not inside double quotes:

```
$s -replace '^(.*?\.exe) .*','$1'
```

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+\.exe)` - one or more character other than whitespace (`\S+`) (or any characters other than a newline, any amount, as few as possible, with `.*?`) followed with a literal `.` and `exe`
- `.*` - a space and then any number of characters other than a newline.

[image]

Comment: I would only recommend not using `\S` here for the fact that path names can definitely include spaces (even if the poster's example paths did not). `.+` would be easiest here, or an inverted character class with all the invalid Windows path characters, which can conveniently be obtained with `[System.IO.Path]::InvalidPathChars -join ''`.

Comment: The paths containing a space are usually enclosed within double quotes and it would be even easier then: [`^"([^"]*\.exe) *" .*`](https://regex101.com/r/gZ9kI8/3). The capturing groups position could be adjusted. Regex for both formats: [`^(?:"([^"]*\.exe) *"|(\S+)) .*`](https://regex101.com/r/gZ9kI8/2).